# Ansible extract sub elements in complex data structure

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to iterate of this data structure and pull out the stdout_lines values. I think the correct approach may be using a loop with sub elements, but I can't figure out the proper syntax. Below is an example of part of my data.

```
ok: [LIN-LNSQ-TEST-01] => {
    "master_mac_address_table": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": false, 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "commands": [
                            "show mac address-table vlan 1"
                        ], 
                        "interval": 1, 
                        "match": "all", 
                        "provider": null, 
                        "retries": 10, 
                        "wait_for": null
                    }
                }, 
                "item": 1, 
                "stdout": [
                    "Mac Address Table\n-------------------------------------------\n\nVlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports\n----    -----------       --------    -----"
                ], 
                "stdout_lines": [
                    [
                        "Mac Address Table", 
                        "-------------------------------------------", 
                        "", 
                        "Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports", 
                        "----    -----------       --------    -----"
                    ]
                ]
            },
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(The name of the variable *master_mac_address_table* is too long. E.g. use *tab* instead. See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).)

The attribute *results* is a list, the subelement *stdout_lines* is a list, and the items of *stdout_lines* are also lists. The lookup plugin *subelements* can't **iterate three nested levels**. You'll have to *include_tasks* in the loop, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat test-loop.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ outer_item.1 }}"
```

Then the tasks

```yaml
    - include_tasks: test-loop.yml
      loop: "{{ query('subelements', tab.results, 'stdout_lines') }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer_item
        label: "{{ outer_item.0 }}"
```

give

```yaml
  msg: Mac Address Table
  msg: '-------------------------------------------'
  msg: ''
  msg: Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
  msg: '----    -----------       --------    -----'
```

---

Let's test it with more elements in the lists, e.g.

```yaml
    tab:
      results:
        - item: 1
          stdout_lines:
            - - "Mac Address Table 1"
              - "test line"
            - - "Mac Address Table 2"
              - "test line"
        - item: 2
          stdout_lines:
            - - "Mac Address Table 3"
              - "test line"
            - - "Mac Address Table 4"
              - "test line"
```

Add *item* of the *result* into the output, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat test-loop.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ outer_item.0.item }} {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ outer_item.1 }}"
```

Then the tasks give

```yaml
  msg: 1 Mac Address Table 1
  msg: 1 test line
  msg: 1 Mac Address Table 2
  msg: 1 test line
  msg: 2 Mac Address Table 3
  msg: 2 test line
  msg: 2 Mac Address Table 4
  msg: 2 test line
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's disappointing there isn't a way to do this without the include.

Comment: I don't think so. I'd simplify the structure and avoid three levels of nested lists. E.g. the data in your example should be a simple list of dictionaries.